# React Native React-Hook-Form Reset

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

how can I reset/clear **<S.Input />** field, I'm using react-hook-form and Typescript.

Code:

```
  const {register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors} = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    register('content')
  }, [register]);

  return(

      <S.Input
        onChangeText={text => {setValue('content', text)}}
        multiline
        textAlignVertical="top"
        maxLength={280}
        placeholder="O que está pensando?"
        selectTextOnFocus={true}
      />
      <S.Button disabled={isLoading} onPress={handleSubmit(handlePost)} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setValue to the default value since the component is not a controlled one or wrapped in the `Controller`.

Wrapping the input in a controller would allow you to use reset.
https://react-hook-form.com/api/#reset

```
const {register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors} = useForm();

// to reset the input
setValue({content: '})
```